# How long should I expect a response from Ubuntu One support?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Half of my files synced with **Ubuntu One** from the past two years are no longer there after upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10.

I contacted support to help me recover the files from a specific time, but no one has responded, and it has been several days.

Is it possible to tell me when the staff have vacation, and when I can expect an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry about that. We have lost most of the members of the support team, and we got a long queue of open tickets while the hiring of new people is completed. It's not an excuse, just an explanation of what's going on.
Some of us from other teams are helping to answer the open questions, so we will get back to normal soon. We are making some changes on the support process so this doesn't happen again.